# Add-PowerBIRow -Dataset Powershell command throwing 404 Not found error

Tags: powershell, powerbi

I'm using the below code to create a dataset in powerbi. The dataset is created successfully in My workspace. I'm able to see it in my dashboard. 
When I'm trying to add a row to the dataset, I'm getting 404 not found error

```
$col1 = New-PowerBIColumn -Name UID -DataType String
$col2 = New-PowerBIColumn -Name Name -DataType String

$tables = New-PowerBITable -Name SampleTables -Columns $col1,$col2

$dataset= New-PowerBIDataSet -Name SampleReports -Tables $tables

Add-PowerBIDataSet -DataSet $dataset -WorkspaceId <<ID>>

//The dataset has been reflected in the respesctive Workspace.

$Info = New-Object 'System.Collections.Generic.List[String]'
$Info.Add('def')
$Info.Add('xyz')

Add-PowerBIRow -DatasetId <<DatasetID>> -TableName tables -Rows $Info- 
WorkspaceId <<ID>>

//Getting the below error
Add-PowerBIRow : Operation returned an invalid status code 'NotFound'
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-PowerBIRow -Dataset $dataset-TableName SampleTables -Rows $ ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo   
: WriteError: (Microsoft.Power...a.AddPowerBIRow:AddPowerBIRow) [Add- 
PowerBIRow], HttpOperationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Operation returned an invalid status code 
'NotFound',Microsoft.PowerBI.Commands.Data.AddPowerBIRow
```

Comment: Shouldn't `-TableName` have `$tables` passed in rather than `tables`?

Answer (score 0):

[Add-PowerBIRow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoftpowerbimgmt.data/add-powerbirow?view=powerbi-ps) method expects string for the value of `TableName` parameter, while it looks like you tried to pass the object (not sure did you miss `$` here or in your code too). Just pass the table name as a string

```
Add-PowerBIRow -DatasetId <<DatasetID>> -TableName 'SampleTables' -Rows $Info -WorkspaceId <<ID>>
```

or

```
Add-PowerBIRow -DatasetId <<DatasetID>> -TableName $tables.Name -Rows $Info -WorkspaceId <<ID>>
```